# Can not put single artist in more than one figure

Tags: matplotlib, plot, python-3.6

Here is my issue.

I create a function that plot a list of circles.
I need to plot my circle C1 first with a circle C2 then with C3.... until C40.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

def plot_circle(Liste_circles):


    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))   
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # On définie un fond blanc
    ax.set_facecolor((1, 1, 1))

    ax.set_xlim(-5, 15)
    ax.set_ylim(-6, 12)    

    for c in Liste_circles:
        ax.add_patch(c)

    plt.show()
```

Now I create C1:

```
C1=Circle(xy=(3, 4), radius=2, fill=False, color='g')
```

An finally I try to plot it.
The first plot worked:

```
C2=Circle(xy=(6, 3), radius=4, fill=False, color='b')
plot_circle([C1,C2])
```

The second one failed:

```
C3=Circle(xy=(7, 2), radius=4, fill=False, color='b')
plot_circle([C1,C3])
```

with the error:

> RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure

I can make it worked by doing:

```
C1=Circle(xy=(3, 4), radius=2, fill=False, color='g')
C3=Circle(xy=(7, 2), radius=4, fill=False, color='b')
plot_circle([C1,C3])
```

How can I do to plot my circle C1 with 40 other circles without having to recreate C1 each time? (My program took 10min to create C1 throught a complicated algorithme, I cannot recreate it at each of the 40 plot....).

Comment: I think the error is pretty self explanatory. It tells you that you cannot put the circle (`C1`) in more than one figure. So either put them all in once cell, or run the cell where you define the circles before running the cell which uses them.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It's all working as expected. See [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLCJJ.gif).

Comment: It is not useful to answer your question with a new question. This will (1) not be clear to people reading the question, (2) look as if you already found the answer such that people will move on without reading in detail. In sum, this will prevent you from getting an answer. If you think what you have in the answer is clearer than your question, replace it in your question.

Comment: Thank you. I edit my first question and will delete my answer :-)

Comment: I might have a solution, I juste have to create a copy of C1 in my plot function and plot the copy instead of C1 himself. But I do not know how to make a copy of C1..... See my other question: "How to copy a python object/ How to get element of a python object"

Comment: Creating the circle will not take 40 minutes. So this is a design thing: Instead of creating the `Circle` let your program output a tuple of position and radius. Use those to create a circle in each plot.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers!!! I had the color that was very important and that I did not manage to get. But thanks to your "copy" function, I find a solution!!! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to make it work: just do a copy of the circle and plot the copy:

First import copy:

```
from copy import copy
```

then, instead of doing:

```
for c in Liste_circles:
    ax.add_patch(c)
```

we have to do:

```
for c in Liste_circles:
   new_c=copy(c)
   ax.add_patch(new_c)
```

This way we won't plot the same circle (= the same artist) but its copy

Comment: copy() is working ok for Rectangle.  Possibly some "artists" need deepcopy() instead?

Answer (score 1):

Moreover if you are interested you can set the x and y axes regarding the values of the circles:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from copy import copy


def plot_circles (Liste_circles):

    if len(Liste_circles) == 0:
        print('No circles to display')
    else:

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))   
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


        # On définie un fond blanc
        ax.set_facecolor((1, 1, 1))


        # On définie les limites des axes pour que nos cercles soient au centre de notre graphique
        # --> xmin sera le plus petit des x de tous les cercles - 2 fois le plus grand des rayons
        # --> xmax sera le plus grand des x de tous les cercles + 2 fois le plus grand des rayons
        # --> ymin sera le plus petit des y de tous les cercles - 2 fois le plus grand des rayons
        # --> ymax sera le plus grand des y de tous les cercles + 2 fois le plus grand des rayons
        L_x = [c.center[0] for c in Liste_circles]
        L_y = [c.center[1] for c in Liste_circles]
        L_r = [c.radius for c in Liste_circles]

        min_x=min(L_x); max_x=max(L_x);min_y=min(L_y); max_y=max(L_y);max_r=max(L_r)

        xmin = min_x - 2*max_r
        xmax = max_x + 2*max_r

        ymin = min_y - 2*max_r
        ymax = max_y + 2*max_r

        ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
        ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)


        for c in Liste_circles:
            new_c=copy(c)
            ax.add_patch(new_c) 

        plt.show()

C1=Circle(xy=(3, 4), radius=2, fill=False, color='g')
C2=Circle(xy=(6, 3), radius=4, fill=False, color='b')
C3=Circle(xy=(7, 2), radius=4, fill=False, color='r')
```