# Pyplot won't clear figure after using add_artist

Tags: matplotlib

In this toy example, I add [Mario](http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100904023133/spritechronicles/images/1/16/Mario2.png) to a plot using `add_artist`. When I do that, I can't seem to clear the figure. Python throws `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure` when it tries to add mario to the second plot (02.png). Why is this happening? How can I avoid this error? I tried sending a copy of the `AnnotationBbox` to `add_artist`, [following this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654584/3474956), but it did not work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

vortexRF = plt.imread('./mario.png')
imagebox = OffsetImage(vortexRF, zoom=0.03)

for ii in range(3):

   fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
   plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.6, hspace=0.5)

   for jj in range(2):
      for kk in range(2):
         ax[jj, kk].plot([0, 1], [0, 1], label='1')
         ax[jj, kk].plot([0, 1], [0, 1], label='2', ls='--')

   ax[1, 0].legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(.08, 2.85))

   if True: # Switch to control if we add mario
      ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (0, 0), frameon=False)
      cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.7, .92, 0.1, 0.1])
      cbar_ax.add_artist(ab)
      cbar_ax.axis('off')

   plt.savefig('./%02d' % ii)

   # attempt to clear figure
   plt.clf()
   plt.cla()
   plt.close('all')
   ab.remove()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to make Mario run in a rush :) like shown below, I think you need to make a new 'imagebox' every time you add to the axis.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

vortexRF = plt.imread('mario.png')
for ii in range(9):
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
   plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.6, hspace=0.5)
   for jj in range(2):
      for kk in range(2):
         ax[jj, kk].plot([0, 1], [0, 1], label='1')
         ax[jj, kk].plot([0, 1], [0, 1], label='2', ls='--')
   ax[1, 0].legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(.08, 2.85))

   if True: # Switch to control if we add mario
      imagebox = OffsetImage(vortexRF, zoom=0.03)
      ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (0, 0), frameon=False)
      cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1+0.1*ii, .92, 0.1, 0.1])
      cbar_ax.add_artist(ab)
      cbar_ax.axis('off')

   plt.savefig(str(ii)+'.png')
plt.show()
```